# Only 1 of 2 pods deploy, other pod is not authorised to pull container

Tags: openshift-origin

I set up a production project using the same structure as my staging project minus the `BuildConfiguration`s and then tagged my containers from the staging image stream to the prod image stream.

```
oc tag my-staging/nginx:latest my-prod/nginx:prod
oc tag my-staging/gunicorn:latest my-prod/gunicorn:prod
oc tag my-staging/celery-worker:latest my-prod/celery-worker:prod
```

Each of these as a `DeploymentConfig` for 2 replicas. The first two have come up with both pods, but the `celery-worker` container is only coming up with a single pod. The other pod generates an error:

> Failed to pull image
>   "172.x.x.x:5000/my-staging/celery-worker@sha256:xxx":
>   unauthorized: authentication required

I don't get how one kubelet can have access but not another. Especially since all of the other pods are up.

Here's the logs from the registry:

```
10.1.3.1 - - [22/Feb/2016:02:52:58 +0000] "GET /v2/cwl-staging/cwl-leadershift-20-celery-worker/manifests/sha256:7a2608ce648b767d65209410fd9f0e8d2fe3f559367c77ba45ba9a713940f83a HTTP/1.1" 401 176 "" "docker/1.8.2-el7.centos go/go1.4.2 kernel/3.10.0-327.4.5.el7.x86_64 os/linux arch/amd64"
time="2016-02-22T02:52:58.297372303Z" level=error msg="OpenShift access denied: User \"system:serviceaccount:cwl-production:default\" cannot get imagestreams/layers in project \"cwl-staging\"" go.version=go1.4.2 http.request.host="172.30.140.184:5000" http.request.id=71a32c41-9e91-40be-9774-166bfa7264f8 http.request.method=GET http.request.remoteaddr="10.1.3.1:48777" http.request.uri="/v2/cwl-staging/cwl-leadershift-20-celery-worker/manifests/sha256:7a2608ce648b767d65209410fd9f0e8d2fe3f559367c77ba45ba9a713940f83a" http.request.useragent="docker/1.8.2-el7.centos go/go1.4.2 kernel/3.10.0-327.4.5.el7.x86_64 os/linux arch/amd64" instance.id=180a3a82-b568-40ab-aaa0-538588e8e765 vars.name="cwl-staging/cwl-leadershift-20-celery-worker" vars.reference="sha256:7a2608ce648b767d65209410fd9f0e8d2fe3f559367c77ba45ba9a713940f83a" 
time="2016-02-22T02:52:58.297449598Z" level=error msg="error authorizing context: access denied" go.version=go1.4.2 http.request.host="172.30.140.184:5000" http.request.id=71a32c41-9e91-40be-9774-166bfa7264f8 http.request.method=GET http.request.remoteaddr="10.1.3.1:48777" http.request.uri="/v2/cwl-staging/cwl-leadershift-20-celery-worker/manifests/sha256:7a2608ce648b767d65209410fd9f0e8d2fe3f559367c77ba45ba9a713940f83a" http.request.useragent="docker/1.8.2-el7.centos go/go1.4.2 kernel/3.10.0-327.4.5.el7.x86_64 os/linux arch/amd64" instance.id=180a3a82-b568-40ab-aaa0-538588e8e765 vars.name="cwl-staging/cwl-leadershift-20-celery-worker" vars.reference="sha256:7a2608ce648b767d65209410fd9f0e8d2fe3f559367c77ba45ba9a713940f83a"
```

Comment: The registry logs should contain information about the rejected pull attempt.  It's possible this is an unexpected race condition in other the registry or Kubelet.  If you delete the half-pulled pod, what happens?  If it works the second time, please open an issue with the Node logs from that period and the registry logs.  If it persists, attempt to restart the node and see if it the node continues.  Since the images are all in the same namespace I would not expect this behavior due to something you did at the CLI.

Comment: So images share a namespace regardless of imagestreams/projects etc?

Comment: Deleting the pod made no difference. Attached the logs from the registry container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `system:image-puller` role wasn't granted to `my-prod`.

Grant the role on the `my-staging` project:

```
oc policy add-role-to-user system:image-puller system:serviceaccount:my-prod:default -n my-staging
```

Delete the stuck pods so they gain the new credentials to pull the image.

[Appropriate section of the Openshift documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/dev_guide/image_pull_secrets.html).